# android :images not being displayed

Tags: android, image

I am making an android app in which i need to display the remote images in my app 
my using following code. 
but the images are not being displayed:

```
for(int i=0;i<stringOnTextView.length;i++){
    imageUrl = "http://ondamove.it/English/images/users/";
    imageUrl = imageUrl+stringOnTextView[i];
    System.out.println(imageUrl);

    URL myFileUrl = new URL(imageUrl);

    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
    System.out.println(bmImg.toString());
}
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem. thanks

Comment: System.out.println(bmImg); print null or not??

Comment: not it is printing the    android.graphics.Bitmap@405f1c90

Comment: its not even giving any error but the images are not shown

Comment: @ekjyot Image URL contains how many images?

Comment: http://ondamove.it/English/images/users/xtfb35edl3j4d0w6kpej1wpwg0o9y.jpeg

Comment: the problem i think is that the method of donwloading takes a long time , try using an AsynTask and  then display images on the onPostExecute() method

Comment: @Houcine can youi tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

as a completion of my comment , see this three tutorials and you will find out what you should do :) :

[tuto1](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)
  [tuto2](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/908-tutorial-progressbar-running-in-asynctask)
  [tuto3](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx)